# Система рейтинг

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Как организовать систему рейтинга? То есть, сам плагин где 5 звездочек, взаимодействуют с бд, где по этой теме просмотреть можно будет мануал?
нашел вот [сайт](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/content/imposition-of-ratings.html), но как его связать с базой я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да пожалуйста [jQuery Star Rating](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing)
А связь с БД - лучше всего (чтоб без перезагрузки) при клике отправлять аjax запрос в обработчик и обновлять рейтинг.

Comment: а там ссылки Интеграция с базой данных не работают http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Database  
что делать)? сам я сам не построю конструкцию)

Comment: Да суть не в этом, с jQuery знакомы? Как простейший AJAX запрос выполнить знаете? - тогда проблем быть вообще не должно.

Comment: Не знаком, не сколько) и простейший аякс запрос незнаю как выполнить, не как ручки до него не добрались еще...

Comment: Вот http://saintist.ru/2009/08/19/jquery-ajax-rating/ может вам подойдет, там думать вообще не надо :)

Comment: Я уж лучше буду разбирать первый. думать полезно

Comment: Ну вообще да, думать - всегда полезно! Удачи вам!